# Import file in Teradata SQL assistant without user interface?

Tags: teradata

Is there a way to import a .csv into a volatile table in Teradata SQL assistant without using the user dialog?  For example, I am now doing the following:

```
drop table test;
create volatile table test, no fallback, no log
(
Model VARCHAR(50) character set latin not casespecific not null,
HCC VARCHAR(50) character set latin not casespecific not null,
Score float not null
)
on commit preserve rows;

insert into test ('Adult','HHS_HCC001',4.74);
```

And I have about 1000 repeated insert rows.  This is at the beginning of my sql file, so I just run the whole file (including a lot of sql statements after I create the table.

The repeated insert takes quite some time to run.  Is there a command to import a csv file without having to be prompted for the file location using the dialog?  Note that I understand there may be other tools to do this, but all my co-workers use Teradata SQL assistant and won't be able to handle having to open up another tool.

Answer (score 1):

The following should accomplish what you are seeking to do with SQL Assistant:

```
sqla.exe -c <DSN> [[\<user>]\<pwd>] -f <SQL file>
```